# Using the like Clause with a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that is dynamically constructed with variables. I would like for all of my  conditions to also have a like statement.

My Code is:

```
$where .= " AND name=" . "'" . $name . "'";
```

I would like to use:

```
$where .= " AND name Like "%'.$name.'%";
```

But I am unsure how to structure it.

Thanks

Comment: `$where = " AND name LIKE '%$name%'";`. but don't do that. it's vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @MarcB Almost want to give them the benefit of the doubt that `$name` is *not* a passed variable, but who am I kidding.

Comment: @fresh: you can still injection yourself. doesn't matter where the data comes from. if you're using it in an sql context, you have to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

It's looks like you are on the right track.  Like this...

```
$where .= " AND name LIKE '%" . $name . "%'";
```

But, when adding fields to a string, I find is easier to use the php [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf) function.  As an example:

```
$where = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name LIKE '%s' AND status='%s'",
    "%" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "%",
    "active"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
$where .= " AND name Like '%".$name."'%";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$where .= " AND name Like '%$name%'";
```

or

```
$where .= ' AND name Like "%'.$name.'%"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
$where .= " AND name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."%'";
```